# Braintree Orders not Posting to Magento 2.3.3 admin

Tags: magento2, braintree

I am facing an issue on our Magento2.3.3 website when order is placed via Braintree.

Some of the orders are missing in the admin but order confirmation emails are sent to customers. 
Even in the payment logs response is 'success' => 'true' from the Braintree side so the issue seems in Magento code.

Is anyone facing the same issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the orders are in place but aren't shown in the order grid as its asynchron. To be sure just check your database real quick if the order is available in the table sales_order

If so you can disable the async grid if needed here:
Store > Configuration > Advance > Developer > Grid Settings

Comment: I have already checked this but missing orders are not there in sales_order table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this issue as well.  Occasionally an order will process on Braintree but Magento won't finalize the order and save it, so I have no record of it until a customer complains!

Often what I am seeing is

1. the customer still has a cart of items
2. their billing and/or shipping info is not saved (as a default address), which leads me to speculate that this somehow messes up the saving process at the Magento end.

We resort to issuing a credit to the customer and asking them to re-submit the order after verifying that they have address info entered for their profile.  Obviously not at all ideal.  Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.